# Bootstrap modal blocks underlying elements even before it is even called

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, modal-dialog

My bootstrap modal blocks the content of the underlying page even before it is called. If there is a link beneath the screenshot shot showed, it cannot be accessed before modal is called. It acts as a layer. Once modal is called, again we can access the underlying elements.

**Before Accessing Modal:**

[image]

[image]

**Once Modal is accessed:**

[image]

Here is my code in `show.html.erb`. How to tackle it ? Is there any particular place we need to keep our Modal code in our document ?

```
 <!-- Modal for uploading Profile Image -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myPicUploadModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only"></span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Upload Picture</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <!-- Showing Exisiting Profile Image -->
        <% if @user.avatar.present? %>
         <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:profile), class: "img-thumbnail" %>
        <%else%>
         <%= image_tag "missing-profile.png", class: "img-thumbnail" %>
        <%end%>
       <p> </p> 
      <!-- Form to upload new pic -->
       <%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :avatar, label: false %>
       </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <%end%>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 

<div ng-controller = "userLeftPanelCtrl" ng-init = "init()">
<!-- Left Panel of User -->
 <div class="well UserProfileLeftPane span2" >
  <!-- Panel options of User --> 
   <!-- Profile image of user -->
    <div class="UserProfileImageLeftBar">
     <% if @user.avatar.present? %>
      <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:profile), class: "img-thumbnail" %>
     <%else%>
      <%= image_tag "missing-profile.png", class: "img-thumbnail" %>
     <%end%>
     <%= link_to '#' do %>
      <span class="label label-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myPicUploadModal" >Upload Pic</span>
     <%end%>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I put `$('.modal').hide();` after initialization of the modal.  Works, although there are many ways to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The place of the modal code in your HTML does not matter because of the `.modal` class should set the CSS display `property` to `none` (which take no space).

Something in your code (Javascript or CSS) set the CSS display `property` to `block` on initialization. Probably by inline CSS (adding style="display:block") because of closing the modal, which remove the `style="display:block"` solve your problem. Notice that on initialization the modal is not visible even when the display has been set to block due to the `.fade` class which sets the `opacity` to `0`.

You will have to find out what in your code set the CSS display `property` to `block`.

Comment: hey, i have tried few places..but no luck ..i am still unclear on why is my modal though hidden ..but shows in developer tools and its indeed blocking contents beneath it ..what could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried hiding and only showing when active?
like this:

```
.modal-body,
.modal-footer {
    display: none;
}
```

and when active setting it to:

```
.modal-body.active,
.modal-footer.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Souza. Active worked, applying the active pseudoelement to the modal checkbox structure. Nicely, works with strings of modals. Following removes page block, but leaves modals working.

```
label { cursor: pointer; text-align: center; width: initial; }
label:hover { color: dodgerblue; cursor: pointer; }
input#modal1, input#modal2 { left: -200%; position: absolute; top: -200%; }
input#modal1:checked + .modal1, input#modal2:checked + .modal2 { opacity: 1; z-index: 0; }
.modal1, .modal2 { background: white; border-bottom: white solid 1rem; border-radius: 1rem; bottom: 0; height: 70vh; left: 0; margin: auto; overflow: scroll; padding: 5vmin; position: absolute; right: 0; text-align: center; top: 0; width: 70vw; z-index: -99; -moz-background-clip: padding-box; -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; background-clip: padding-box; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5vmin lightgray; box-shadow: 0 0 5vmin lightgray; -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; filter: alpha(opacity=0); opacity: 0; -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease; -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease; -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease; -o-transition: opacity 1s ease; transition: opacity 1s ease; }
.modal1:active, .modal2:active { display: table; z-index: 99; }

<label for="modal1">Modal1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="modal1" />
<article class="modal1">stuff</article>

<label for="modal2">Modal1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="modal2" />
<article class="modal2">stuff</article>
```

'display' weight is applied to body elements, not isolated modal class - modal class is sensitive to z-index styling

element:active display okay - z-index trick needs that table (fyi isolated z-index by adjusting modal's bottom-left-right-top and height-width - box positioning shows (unexpected) proportional-to-displacement resize of modal, so with DISPLAY in focus nix position and focus z-index

my application is for popup info cards - without the modal:active trick, the inactive (invisible) modal rests on top of page, blocking user access to page links - as far as this topic is concerned, that would mean that access to linked buttons on page would also not be accessible, using our layout

same 'hassel using FontAwesome icons as page background - which resolves in a similar style, unless you want to block content theft (thanks fa)

refer to this:

https://designshack.net/preview/37934 (https://designshack.net//tutorialexamples/cssmodal/index.html)

with a heavily scripted example: http://subtlepatterns.com/retina-wood/